# sendmail for mac

Tags: macos, unix, homebrew, package-management

Is there a `sendmail` port for Mac that I can install?

Mac already has a [sendmail](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sendmail.1.html) process.

But that is not what I am looking for. The summary in its doc says:

> sendmail - Postfix to Sendmail compatibility interface
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    The  Postfix sendmail(1) command implements the Postfix to Sendmail compatibility interface.  For the
>    sake of compatibility with existing applications, some Sendmail command-line options  are  recognized
>    but silently ignored.
> ```

For example CentOs7 one can do `yum install sendmail` and it installs version [8.14.7](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/26646892/dir/centos_7/com/sendmail-8.14.7-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html).
There the [doc](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html) says:

> sendmail - an electronic mail transport agent
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>  Sendmail sends a message to one or more recipients, routing the message
>  over whatever networks are necessary.  Sendmail does internetwork for-
>  warding as necessary to deliver the message to the correct place.
> ```

I am looking for the latter sendmail. Is it available in Mac?

Brew does not have it.

```
$ brew search sendmail
==> Searching local taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
==> Searching blacklisted, migrated and deleted formulae...
No formula found for "sendmail".
Closed pull requests:
mailhog 0.1.8 (new formula) (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/44884)
```

Comment: It's available in MacPorts:  https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=sendmail